# quickCheck returns error when comparing zipWith functions

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I created my own myzipWith function and want to compare it with the original zipWith with the use of quickCheck.

```
myzipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
myzipWith a y [] = []
myzipWith a [] y = []
myzipWith a (x:xs) (z:zs) = [a x z] ++ myzipWith a xs zs

prop_zip x y z = myzipWith x y z == zipWith x y z
```

When I run quickCheck by typing quickCheck prop_zip, it returns error:

```
<interactive>:69:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show (a0 -> b0 -> c0))
        arising from a use of `quickCheck'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the expression: quickCheck prop_zip
      In an equation for `it': it = quickCheck prop_zip

<interactive>:69:12: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `c0' arising from a use of `prop_zip'
      prevents the constraint `(Eq c0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `c0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Eq b, Eq a) => Eq (Either a b)
          -- Defined in `Data.Either'
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in `integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type'
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 73 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the first argument of `quickCheck', namely `prop_zip'
      In the expression: quickCheck prop_zip
      In an equation for `it': it = quickCheck prop_zip
```

What is the propblem here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two unrelated problems here:

- The type is ambiguous. Hence `` Ambiguous type variable `c0' ``.
  Your function could be used as `(Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`, or just as well `(Char -> Bool -> String) -> [Char] -> [Bool] -> [String]` etc. etc.. It doesn't overly matter which of these you test, but you should pick one (if you don't, then even if it does work that may be due to defaulting to `()`, which is probably a bad idea because all `()` values are trivially equal, so your tests might not show up any bugs).
- The first argument is a function. QuickCheck can *generate* functions automatically, but for a test case it also wants to *show* them, and that's generally not possible.
  The standard solution is to generate a [`Fun`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Fun) instead, and convert that using [`applyFun2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:applyFun2) or [`Fn2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:Fn2). (Funnily enough, the documentation for these contains an example for `zipWith`...)

Another unrelated thing I would recommend is to use [`===`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:-61--61--61-) for equality checking, not `==`. The former will not only tell you whether or not your function gives the same result as the reference, but also *which* result it is in case it's different.

Comment: One ambiguity fix is to import `Test.QuickCheck.Poly` and use `A`, `B`, `C`, `OrdA`, `OrdB`, or `OrdC`. Alternatively, you can use Template Haskell stuff in `Test.QuickCheck.All`, *most* of which defaults polymorphic properties to `Integer`.